# Learning Curve of GameMaker and its limits

Tags: game-maker

I am a Data Scientist and the last couple of years, I work also as a Game Designer (not Game Development). I have not thought to create a game by myself, up to now.

As a DS, I know programming, but I am not interested to learn a new language only for a game development. Like Unity or C/C++.

Also, I am not keen on creating a 3D game which may take 1-2 years to finish it working part time on it. So, I am closer to a 2D game, with the simplest one like Flappy Bird and the most difficult one like Angry Birds for mobile devices.

After a short research, I found GameMaker which seems reasonable in the difficulty. However, I would like to know what is its learning curve based on a pure programming language for gaming like Unity, plus if it has any limits of what you could do on a 2D game.

Comment: The learning curve is a concept that measures how an **average** person can learn something or achieve a task based on the creator of the term Hermann Ebbinghaus. Focus on the word "average". This means that a learning curve is not an opinion-based concept. As for the limits, I think it's not the case here. Define if you can create a multiplayer game in GameMaker or not for example, is not an opinion-based answer as well. Please reconsider to open the question or point me another place to discuss it thoroughly. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome to post a question on meta specifically about this. It can be addressed as its own question better than in the comments.